# не могу правильно вставить explode

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос у меня скрипт с добавлением изображений на сервер и путь к ним в бд, вот не могу сделать так чтобы в бд подпадали названия всех изображений через запятую в строку в одном поле . у меня попадает только одно последние изображение в бд, а на сервер грузятся все изображения.
вот код

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION[login])) {
    exit ("Страница не найдена!");
}
mysql_connect("", "", "");
mysql_select_db("");
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
    foreach ($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'] as $k => $v) {
        $err = array();
        {
            // Каталог, в который мы будем принимать файл:

            $uploaddir = 'images/';

            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$k]);
            // Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
            if (!copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile)) {

                $error[] = "<div class='dannye'><h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</div></h3>";
            }
            if (count($error) == 0)

                $uploaddire = $uploaddir;
            $uploadfilee = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$k];
            //$uploadfiles = explode(',', $uploadfilee);
            //$getMime =  $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$k];

            {
                $sqlimage = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET catalog='" . $uploaddire . "', filename='" . $uploadfilee . "' WHERE login='" . $_GET['login'] . "'");
                //выводим результат\
                if (isset($sqlimage)) {
                    echo "<div class='dannye'><p>даные вставлены </p> " . $uploadfilee . "</div>";
                } else {

                    print "<div class='dannye'><b>При добавленнии изображения произошли следующие ошибки:</b><br>";

                    foreach ($error AS $errors) {

                        print  $errors . "<br>";

                    }
                    print  "</div>";
                }
            }

        }

    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Загрузка изображения на сервер</title>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .dannye {
            position: relative;
            top: 370px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <p>Загрузка изображения на сервер</p>
</header>

<div class="content">
    <?
    mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("");
    print_r($_GET['login']);

    ?></p>
    <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='uploadfile[]' multiple='true'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Загрузить'></form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы в цикле обновляете каждый раз одну и туже строку в бд:  `"' WHERE login='" . $_GET['login'] . "'"` - эта конструкция находит строку где логин пользователя соответствует логину из `$_GET['login']` и обновляете там поля на те значения которые лежат в `$uploaddire` и `$uploadfilee`

Comment: не помогла зарыл foreach до sql

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы в цикле перетираете значение в бд

```
$sql "UPDATE `users` ".
     "SET catalog='" . $uploaddire . "', filename='" . $uploadfilee . "' ".
     "WHERE login='" . $_GET['login'] . "'";
$sqlimage = mysql_query($sql);
```